# How can a dropdown be stylized when using twitter bootstrap with simple_form in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using simple_form and twitter-bootstrap-rails gems. Every thing is working fine but somehow drop-down is not getting stylized by twitter bootstrap rails ..it shows like normal forms.

```
<%= f.input :category, :collection => ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
    :input_html => {:class => 'dropdown'}, :label => 'Send To', prompt: "Choose From List" %>
```

IMAGE OF DROPDOWN SHOWING:

[image]

IMAGE OF DROPDOWN NEEDED AS IN BOOTSTRAP

[image]

Comment: Please share the code. Else no one can help you

Comment: <%= f.input :category, :collection => ["one", "two", "three", "four"],:input_html => { :class => 'dropdown'}, :label => 'Send To', prompt: "Choose From List" %>

Comment: @RahulInsane did your question got resolved? ".form-control" as suggested by Kirti Thorat is correct as for the Bootstrap goes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get stylized dropdowns with [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) is to use [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select). There is a [Rails Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-select-rails/versions/1.6.3) for it; add to your Gemfile and do a `bundle`:

```
gem 'bootstrap-select-rails'
```

You need to add it to your stylesheet

```
@import "bootstrap-select";
```

and Javascript.

```
//= require bootstrap-select
```

Now, all you need to do is use `input_html: {class: 'selectpicker'}` in your existing `f.input`:

```
<%= f.input :category, :collection => ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
:input_html => {:class => 'selectpicker'}, :label => 'Send To', prompt: "Choose From List" %>
```

and then initialize the Javascript (which is a one-off regardless of how many selectpickers you have):

```
<%= javascript_tag "$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();" %>
```

Restart your app and your input dropdown should render with Bootstrap styling.

Some extra info that may be useful: you can disable the prompt item so that it cannot be selected from the dropdown by adding the `disabled` class to the item. I couldn't find any guidance on [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) how to apply a style to one element of a collection but I came up with the below that does it to all such prompts:

```
<%= javascript_tag "$('li[data-original-index=0]').addClass('disabled');" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= f.input :category, :collection => ["one", "two", "three", "four"],:input_html => { :class => 'dropdown'}, :label => 'Send To', prompt: "Choose From List" %>
```

With

```
<%= f.input :category, :collection => ["one", "two", "three", "four"],:input_html => { :class => 'form-control'}, :label => 'Send To', prompt: "Choose From List" %>
```

`.form-control` is used to style select tags. All textual `<input>, <textarea>, and <select>` elements with `.form-control` are set to width: 100%; by default. Wrap labels and controls in `.form-group` for optimum spacing.

`dropdown` is not used for `select` tags. See details [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

Comment: kirti..it dint work still.. i have changed the class name in .js file also though ..

Comment: one quick question...does class name will change the behaviour ? ..as it will be considered only text right ?

Comment: class name has to be present, that is what is going to style the select.

Comment: so based on class names the styling changes and we cant give any random class name as i gave 'dropdown' ? is my understanding right ?

Comment: as per other answers in other posts ..i have tried to change the priority of //== jquery after //==bootstrap also ...but nothing worked

Comment: I added images of my dropdown