# Simple form input as dropdown not select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a input with a collection that should display as a drop down but instead it's displaying as a select box. How do i make it a drop down?

```
<%= f.input :fund, collection: funds, prompt: 'Select Fund', label: false, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `as: :select` to your HTML and remove the `multiple: true` attribute. The select tag as a dropdown list does not support multiple selections without a JavaScript library like Select2.

```
<%= f.input :fund, as: :select, collection: funds, prompt: 'Select Fund', label: false %>
```

Here is an example of each type of select: http://jsfiddle.net/scarver2/s1nckfq5/

CITE: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278096) but you don't say what context (web framework) you're using.

You can use [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select). There is a [Rails Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-select-rails/versions/1.6.3) for it. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278096) for details.